# how to insert not filter variable into database?

Tags: magento-1.9

i m using ajax to insert variable into database i have two input box one is email other is company name i m using filter_var to check email validation but now problem is how to insert company name without used this validation?

Here is my code

```
<?php    
 require_once('app/Mage.php');
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 Mage::app('admin');
 $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
 $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
 $company = $_REQUEST['company'];
 $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
 $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
 if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO guest_user_track(Guser_mail,Guser_name) VALUES 
   ('{$email}','{$company}')";
$writeConnection->query($query);
echo json_encode(array("message"=>"success"));
}
else {
 echo json_encode(array("message"=>"error"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Validation i suggest you should use Zend framework validation and for text based validation you should use : **Zend_Validate_Alpha**

you can check following link with all validation and patterens

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html

hope it will help

Comment: my problem is not validation working ...actually my email validation response is correct but i want to insert company name and email(after validation) but its only inserting email not name. because name also using mail validation i thnk so i want to know how to use this validation so i can insert both variable in my database

Comment: i suggest you should use Zend_framework validation which is builtin supported, otherwise you have use regex with filter_var for logic implementation. Secondly i assume your form validation pass through and only issue is on server side.